# How to save object in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, retain

I want to assign a object to NSMutableDictionary in one method and want to use it in another method as below:

```
- (void) aaa {
  NSString* aa = @"hello";
  [self.pcs setObject:aa forKey:@"a"];
}

- (void) bbb {
  NSLog(@"ccc %@", self.pcs[@"a"]);
}
```

pcs is a property in @interface

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary* pcs;
```

if I call `aaa` and `bbb` in another method, I want method `bbb` to print the log of `ccc hello`, but the result is `ccc (null)`

Can anybody tell me how to store object in NSMuableDictionary?

Comment: Did you ever actually create the NSMutableDictionary??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you initialise self.pcs?

If self.pcs is null, of course self.pcs[@"a"] is null

Comment: So sorry, I'm totally new with objective c, I did initialize self.pcs, thank you.

Comment: Show how you initialized the dictionary, I reckon @TinyFool is right.

Comment: ok, I'm new with English, a typo, I did not initialize self.pcs. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Just include this line before setting the object for Key :-

```
self.pcs=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

*Edit:- 
Until your mutabledictionary object is not created. You cannot set the object for key.*

Answer (score 0):

Using literal syntax:

```
self.pcs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSObject *someObject = [NSObject new];
self.pcs[@"KEY"] = someObject;
```